# Gallery: Effect in item selected

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-gallery

I need to have an scroll with items together, and the selected item should expand a part down.

[image]

I am currently using a Gallery (I tried with viewflow and viewpager, but the items have much space between them), but I need to know how can I do this effect.

I have 2 ideas, but i don't know how can I implement it.

1) The expandable part is a LinearLayout with visibility=gone, and when the item is selected, this layout should be visible.  (Gallery do not have "onItemSelectedListener")

2) Treat each element as a fragment (once I use a Viewpager that use this,  https://github.com/mrleolink/SimpleInfiniteCarousel)

It does not necessarily have to be a gallery, any idea is welcome

I am working on an Activity.

Comment: You shouldn't use gallery even if you are able to get the desired output from it. It has been deprecated since API level 16, hence you loose roughly 65% of the users(as of this day) from the get go.

Comment: can you please elaborate your question...

Comment: @Shakti , while I agree that OP should not use Gallery, deprecated does not necessarily mean OP will lose any users. AFAIK, Gallery still exists up to KitKat, but its use is discouraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the behavior that you want.  Some questions can more than one item be expanded at a time?  Do you want the views to be paged (snap into place) or smooth scroll them?

One Suggestion I have is to make a custom view for the individual cells.  Then add them programmatically to a HorizontalScrollView Object.

```
 HorizontalScrollView hsv = new HorizontalScrollView(activity);
 LinearLayout hll = new LinearLayout(activity);
 hll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
 for(int i=0;i<items.length();i++){
      hsv.addView(new CustomExpandView(item));
 }
```

The CustomExpandView would be used for your cells and could be something like this...

```
public class CustomExpandView extends RelativeLayout implements OnClickListener {

MyActivity mActivity = null;
ImageView ivImage, ivOverImage;
RelativeLayout rlView;

public CustomExpandView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initialize();
}

public CustomExpandView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initialize();
}

public void initialize() {
    mActivity = (MyActivity) this.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_cell_expand, this, true);

            //you can initialize subviews here
    rlView = (RelativeLayout) getChildAt(0);
    ivImage = (ImageView) rlView.getChildAt(0);
    ivOverImage = (ImageView) rlView.getChildAt(1);

 rlView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            LinearLayout expand = v.findViewById(R.id.view_i_want_to_expand);
            if(hasFocus)
                expand.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            else
                expand.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You gave the answer yourself. You can use a ViewPager, with fragments, and have an animation to extend the lower part of the window. Depends on whether you  want the windows to be full screen or not. A viewpager doesn't necessarily need fragments, you can use ordinary views, and an appropriate adapter. Just play with it and see which solution you like most.

Next time, just create the code and the app, and ask a much more specific question, with code to illustrate the issue you're experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply define a `TableView` with just one `TableRow` (or as many as you need) and set a `onClickListener` for each of those `View`s inside the `TableRow`, which would make that on any click, the selected `View` would expand itself.

I don't know whether you'll have a static number of `View`s inside that row or you'll construct them dynamically, but this should work for any of them, the real "work" here about populating that row.

Once you have your row of `View`s, simply declare an `onClickListener()` on each of them. For example, this should be enough:

```
OnClickListener myListener = new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(final View v) {
    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  }
};
```

And as the `onClick` event for all of your items inside the `TableRow`:

for (View v : myTableRowViews)
     v.setOnClickListener(myListener);

This has a disadvantage: You can know which `View` has been clicked for selection, but natively you cannot know which has been deselected, so you'll need to keep track of the last selected tab declaring a class-wide variable and setting it each time `onClick()` is fired, so your listener will become something like this:

```
// In your class declare a variable like this
View lastSelected = null;

OnClickListener myListener = new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(final View v) {
    if (lastSelected != null)
      lastSelected.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    lastSelected = v;
  }
};
```

Additionally, you can set an animation to the effect to make it more attractive, but mainly this is the idea.

One last thing: To make it work this way you'll need to set the `layout_height` of both your `TableRow` and the `View` items inside, so it may expand afterwards when you set the additional part as visible. Also, to make it look good all of your `View`s will have to be the same height (both in the reduced and extended state).